# Import specific method signature in Scala

Tags: scala, importerror, ambiguous

Is there a manner to import a specific method signature?

```
def test() {
  lazy val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger("AndroidProxy")
  import log.{error, debug, info, trace}

  trace("This is a test")
  trace "This is also"   // <- This line will not compile 
}
```

Perhaps it's not possible, but my primary goal is to allow this without adding in a new method. I've tried these to no avail

```
import log.{error => error(_:String)}
import log.{error(x: String) => error(x)}
```

I suppose the primary challenge is that all of the methods take one argument. I can call no-argument methods without (), and I can create a chain of method calls that omits the .'s e.g. `foo getX toString`, but I don't know how to create an arity-1 call automatically

This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905834/scala-call-logging-method-without-log-xxxx/14905931#14905931).

Comment: That line will not compile because it is plain illegal. The error message is just an artifact of the compiler trying to make sense of it, I expect. Remove the line above, while preserving the empty line between the import and it, and see what it shows.

Comment: Yup, it's a completely different error. I'll update the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with the code:

```
trace "This is also"   // <- This line will not compile
```

is *not* that you're somehow importing too many overloaded variants of `trace` - it's that you can't use Scala's infix notation this way. An expression like:

```
e op
```

is interpreted as a "Postﬁx Operation" (see section 6.12.2 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)), equivalent to the call:

```
e.op
```

So your code would be equivalent to:

```
trace."This is also"
```

which is of course a compile error.

If you instead use an "Inﬁx Operation" of the form `e1 op e2` (section 6.12.3 of the [Scala Language Specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf)), then there aren't any problems even if the method is overloaded:

```
scala> class Logger { def trace(s: String) = "1arg"; def trace(i: Int, s: String) = "2arg" }
defined class Logger

scala> val log = new Logger
log: Logger = Logger@63ecceb3

scala> log trace "This is also"
res0: String = 1arg
```

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not a way to import a specific method signature.

Comment: To elaborate... Importing is about names alone. So no, you cannot import only a particular signature, only the entire overload set for a given name.